# HTML multiple svg file convert into png

Tags: c#, asp.net, svg, jquery-svg

Currently, in Asp.Net project I have two svg files (tags) on single page.
I am using [Svg Rendering Engine](http://svg.codeplex.com/) converting svg to png. 
it allow only one tag for image conversion. if i have multiple svg tags present in it, then it throw an error.
What is best solution for this conversion. 
Should I use Html to Png conversion. which Html to Png conversion will help.

Comment: What does `if i have multiple svg tags present` mean?  What does your SVG look like? What kind of result are you trying to get?

Comment: I have two svg files, one is as template and another is overlapping that template and drawing some design. Now i want that complete result in Png format file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used  [hiqpdf](http://www.hiqpdf.com/) to convert HTML to PDF.